# Enable users to perform submission but not saving?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I have a few SharePoint forms that only allow users to submit, not save(edit). Because the admin doesn't want users to edit whatever they submitted. If they want to edit anything, they'll need to inform the admin and admin will help to edit.

I created a permission level with the below permissions.

1. Add Items  -  Add items to lists, add documents to document libraries, and add Web discussion comments.
2. View Items  -  View items in lists, documents in document libraries, and view Web discussion comments.
3. Open Items  -  View the source of documents with server-side file handlers.
4. View Pages  -  View pages in a Web site.
5. Open  -  Allows users to open a Web site, list, or folder in order to access items inside that container.

I took away this below permission but users still able to see the Save button and perform edit.

Edit Items  -  Edit items in lists, edit documents in document libraries, edit Web discussion comments in documents, and customize Web Part Pages in document libraries.

Please help me on this, I want to allow users to submit form only, not edit.
Thanks in advance and have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no permission that allows you to only edit.

You could however replace/modify the item permissions using a workflow (on create) in SPD. Use a workflow step with elevated priviliges then add the permissions step of your choice.

The group only allowed to submit should have only read permissions in the end. It depends on your permissions structure which permissions need to be edited.

Alternatively I can suggest using two lists, on the first The submitters have contribute rights, on the second read rights. In SPD: When an item is added to the first copy The values to a new item in the second and delete the item in the first list.

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks for your reply. I'm thinking, for the form library listed on the left panel, can I set it to show certain of it to certain of users only?

Comment: @EngLoon You're welcome. Yes you should be able to set an audience in the settings of the navigation item. 

Go to site settings -> navigation, edit the navigation item.

Comment: Hi @EngLoon if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Hi Jan. Sorry for late reply. I'm using Sharepoint 2007, I went to site settings but can't find Navigation, Edit and navigation item. Please advice.